# SharpDevelop C# Windows Application is ready to deploy .. how to move sql database to client pc? what else i need?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, project, sharpdevelop

I just done with programming client's application by SharpDevelop C# .. Now i need to install the software to customer ... What i need exactly to do?

I know some steps .. but i'm not sure if something is missing ..

1)Build Project to .exe

2)Move built project to client pc.

3)Move database to client pc.   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I'm using MSSQL sqlexpress .. How to move the database to client pc?

4)change connection string in configuration file to suit the new changes.

5)installing the following in client pc:

- SQL Server Management Studio

  - Net Framework

so my question is in number (5) how to move database ...

my 2nd question is anything missing that i have to do?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Tip: Install it on a PC that _isn't_ the clients or your development machine. Then you can test your deployment process.

Comment: thanks man .. i appreciate your concern ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your steps are qualified for many Winform Apps, so you can do it as your steps, then to test it on a new machine. if it works well, then you can do the same things on your clients' PCs.
in other kinds of apps, there may be other things to do, such as set environment variables, add register keys, and so on. but I think they are unnecessary to do them, so you just test as your steps.
about you asked how to move database, I usually copy the mdf file and ldf file together to clients' PCs, then attach them into SQLServer Management Studio.
good luck!

Comment: i would appreciate if you would show guide me to link where to get the mdf and ldf files ... and how to attach them in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: here is a link hope to be useful to you. http://www.codeweblog.com/mdf-file-into-sqlserver-database-to-transfer/